# Sending data from HTML5 to PHP service

Tags: php, html, web-services

i'd like to ask question about using php web service in html5. In my first html file I want to get a input from textbox when button is clicked, I want to send this input to my php web service and then print it in the second html file. I've get it done by the code below but i want to send it to seperated php web service.

1st html file.

```
     function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('form1').action = action;
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
---------------------------------------------------------
<form action="deneme.php" id="form1" name="form1">
                    <input type="text" name="searchtxt" id="searchtxt" placeholder="Write something to search"></br>
                    <div align="center">
                <input type="button" onclick="submitForm('deneme.php')" value="Find Location" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-inline="true"/></div>
                </form>
```

since I used deneme.php in onclick i had to have my 2nd page as php which is what i want to prevent.

deneme.php file

```
    <?php 
    $search=$_REQUEST['searchtxt'];

if(empty($search)){
    echo ("<br/>You don't enter anything.");}
     else{

  echo ($search);
}
?>
```

As i mentioned above, i want to send variable to seperated php web service and get back response but having my second page also html. How should i modify my program to observe this.

Thanks

Comment: Hm, i think you don't understand basics of the service request/response and server side languages.

Comment: I know, i got it wrong, but i have made it work, now i want to modify it into right way what i did in wrong way.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. But first you have to know how php is workikng and the basics of php and html.

Comment: As i said, I just need to have my php web service seperated from my html files. Thanks anyways.